# Pandas - apply multiplication factor to column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have I dataframe:

```
cases_df = pd.DataFrame(list(cases.items()),
                   columns=['day', 'cases'])
```

where `case.items()` is structured like so:

```
([('2020-04-04T00:00:00Z', 10360), ('2020-04-05T00:00:00Z', 11130), ('2020-04- 06T00:00:00Z', 12161)])
```

how can I apply a multiplication factor, say 'x', only to 'cases' column?

example `x = 100`:

```
'2020-04-04T00:00:00Z'  1036000
'2020-04-05T00:00:00Z'  1113000
'2020-04- 06T00:00:00Z' 1216100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
cases_df.cases*=100
cases_df
                     day    cases
0   2020-04-04T00:00:00Z  1036000
1   2020-04-05T00:00:00Z  1113000
2  2020-04- 06T00:00:00Z  1216100
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cases_df['cases'] *= x
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, since df['column'] syntax is preferred to df.column, since second one doesn't work if a column name has a space or a special character in it (which should never happen, but it does).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
cases_df['cases']  = x*cases_df['cases']
```